# PING: transmit failed. General failure

Tags: windows-7, networking

I'm getting this error when trying to ping anything. Yesterday all was ok, no new software installed and no any other OS changes.
My connection is ADSL router via Ethernet port. Router's indicators show "everything is ok" Ping to 127.0.0.1 works ok.
I've tried reconnecting, reinstalling driver, etc - no success.
Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1
Ideas?

Comment: what firewall do you use ?

Comment: @Revolter, The problem stays when firewall is disabled.

Comment: So, you can ping loopback, can you ping your router? Anything else on the network? Is the only problem getting outside (google.com, etc)? Also, have you tried turning it off and on again (with the cable unplugged)?

Comment: No, cannot ping router. Only loopback works. All obvious stuff like off/on doesn't work.